# Ring Homomorphism Identities

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

Suppose $f: R\rightarrow S$ is a ring homomorphism such that $R$ is a ring with identity $1_R$. Prove that $f(1_R)$ is the multiplicative identity in $f(R)$

I am stumped on this one. Learning undergrad abstract algebra on my own to prepare.

Any pointers to begin?

Comment: What you do there is nonsense. Why is $f(r) = 1_S$ for arbitrary $r\in R$? What you have to prove is that $f(1_R)s = sf(1_R) = s$ for all $s\in S$. For this you actually need that $f$ is bijective.

Comment: Thanks. I will update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $f$ to be surjective.

Let $s\in S$ then we show $f(1_R)\cdot s = s$. Since $f$ is onto so there exists $r\in R$ such that $f(r)=s$ and so $f(1_R)\cdot s=f(1_R)\cdot f(r)=f(1_R\cdot r)= f(r)=s$ as $f$ is a homomorphism  and similarly we can show $s\cdot f(1_R) =s$.

Since $s\in S$ is arbitrary hence $f(1_R)=1_S$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your help.